# JQuery UI Datepicker CSS to format table data (td)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use the JQuery datepicker to select a date for a reservation form. There are some dates that aren't selectable, so I disabled them. This works prety fine. Now I tried to mark the arrival and departures dates before and after the reservation.

This works fine, if the reservation doesn't begin at the start of the month. But there are some cases, that doesn't work.

Visit http://bnob.ch/de/index.php for the example. Look at the reservations in august. The arrival and departure date of the first reservation doesn't work, the second works correctly.

CSS code:

```
#ui-datepicker-calendar {
border-collapse: separate;
}
td.disabled {
padding: 1px;
background-color: red;
}
td.departure {
padding: 1px 0 0 1px;
background-color: red;
}
td.arrival {
padding: 0 1px 1px 0;
background-color: red;
}
```

What is the different between this two entries? I didn't find any with firebug. It looks exactly the same.
Is an inheritance in the table active, that I didn't see yet?

Thank you for any informations

Best regards Denis

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve with the padding, changing the colour of the borders with an `!important` flag would probably be a cleaner and more reliable solution.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you to get me on the right way.

The border was also my first decision, but I didn't see the posibility to select the child element (anchor or span). The declaration on the td don't look very pretty with a border.

To style your border you should use it on the child elements:

```
.disabled span { border: 1px solid red !important; }

.otherStyle a { border-bottom: 1px solid red !important; border-right: 1px solid red !important }
```

Comment: is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: No problem, make sure you accept it as the answer in case it is your final solution.